# Confusion about type conversion

Tags: powershell

I wrote a function that calculates a factorial. Was trying to make sure that it gives an error when the input value is not an integer, but PowerShell automagically converts the input. Is there a way to make sure non-integers are caught and an error is displayed.

```
function Get-Factorial ([int]$x) {
    if ($x -isnot [system.int32]) {
        return "error"
    }
    if ($x -eq 0) {
        return 1
    }
    return $x * (Get-Factorial($x - 1))
}
```

Comment: Running `Get-Factorial -x 'abcd'` returns a type error before the function can run. Take the `[int]` off of your parameter and your if statement will get hit

Answer (score 0):

Sure, do not tell Powershell that you would like an [int] as the first param

```
function Get-Factorial ($x) {
    if($x -isnot [system.int32]){
       throw [System.ArgumentException]
    }
    if ($x -eq 0) {
        return 1
    }
             return $x * (Get-Factorial($x - 1))
}

PS C:\Users\jos> Get-Factorial -x 1.1 
System.ArgumentException
At line:1 char:1
+ throw [System.ArgumentException]
…
# or 
PS C:\Users\jos> Get-Factorial 1.1 
System.ArgumentException
At line:1 char:1
+ throw [System.ArgumentException]
...
```

Comment: is there a way to avoid using parenthesis for functions so that instead of            get-factorial(-1.1) I can do get-factorial -1.1. The issue is that when avoiding the parenthesis, powershell thinks the input is a string (when using negative numbers)

Comment: yes , in fact adding the brackets is a bad practice ( sorry ) 

better :  
```

Get-Factorial -x 1.1 
Get-Factorial 1.1 

```

Comment: @user242114 Check out https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-functions.html. `Function Get-Factorial { Param ($Value)}` allows `Get-Factorial -Value 1` or `Get-Factorial 1`

Comment: sorry duct_tape_coder, but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: anyone have an idea?